# SweetAlert enviar coordenadas por whatsapp

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, sweetalert2

**Estoy tratando de armar una funcion con sweetalert2 para enviar coordenadas por whatsapp con la api y googlemaps enviar los valores de coordenadas**

**CODIGO HTML**

**SCRIPT**

*Lo que no puedo lograr es mediante ajax y fetch de SweetAlert2, es el enviar los valores de las variables en el mensaje de whatsapp.*

```
 function mensaje() {

            var reclamo = $("span[name=reclamo]").text();
            var lat = $("input[name=lat]").val();
            var lng = $("input[name=lng]").val();

           
            var aux3 = [lat, lng];




            Swal.fire({
                title: 'Ingrese numero de celular',
                input: 'text',
                inputAttributes: {
                    autocapitalize: 'off'
                },
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonText: 'Enviar',
                confirmButtonColor: '#13bb95',
                showLoaderOnConfirm: true,

                preConfirm: (aux) => {
                    return
                    fetch(`https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=549264${aux}&text=hola,%20Este%20reclamo%20ingreso%20recientemente%20${reclamo}%20%20https://www.google.com.ar/maps/place/${aux3}`)
                        .then(response => {
                            if (!response.ok) {
                                throw new Error(response.statusText)
                            }
                            return response.json()
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            Swal.showValidationMessage(
                                `Request failed: ${error}`
                            )
                        })

                },

                allowOutsideClick: () => !Swal.isLoading()

            }).then((result) => {

                if (result.isConfirmed) {
                    Swal.fire({
                        title: `${result.value.aux}'mensaje`,
                    })

                }

            })

        }
```

[image: Ejemplo]

**Alguna Ayuda se lo agradeceria**

Comment: ¿Por qué tienes un `return` al comienzo del `preConfirm`?

Comment: asi esta el ejemplo de ajax request con sweetalert

Comment: es la funcion por defecto de sweet alert. no se como hacer escuchar o capturar esos datos q se introducen en el input del sweet alert para despues concatenarlo a la funcion fetch para armar la url

Answer (score 0):

**CODIGO HTML**

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10"></script>

 <button type="submit"  onclick=mensaje();                               
   class="btn btn-outline-success waves-effect waves-light ml-2"><i
   class="mdi mdi-link-variant mr-1"></i>Mensaje
 </button>

 <div class="form-group">
     <label>Nombre y Apellido</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese su nombre y apellido"
      disabled />
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
     <label>Latitud</label>
    <input data-parsley-type="number" type="text" class="form-control" id="lat"   name="lat"                          required />
</div>
 <div class="form-group">
     <label>Longitud</label>
     <input data-parsley-type="number" type="text" class="form-control" id="lng"  name="lng"  required  />
</div>
```

Comment: Es una respuesta o parte de tu pregunta_?

Comment: Si es parte de tu pregunta, editala, hay una opcion para que puedas editar la pregunta, despue elimina esa respuesta si no la es

Comment: es el codigo html de los input y button